# how to connect two mysql databases in two servers inside trigger

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

Is there any way to connect 2 databases with different server inside the trigger?

I have 2 databases with 2 database server.

First server and database are the main databases and second server and database is the seconder database.

I want to sync both databases with each other. So I am using trigger but the trigger will update only same server database data but I want to sync data with two MySQL databases in two servers.

Is there anyway?

**EDIT**

Is there any way for database replication with multiple database servers?

Comment: [MySQL - Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html) `Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master) to be copied to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves). [...] Depending on the configuration, you can replicate all databases, selected databases, or even selected tables within a database.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have both same database structure then you can use master-master replication or master-slave replication

Comment: Yes Both databases have the same structure.

Comment: both are working same time or only one working and other is the backup server?

Comment: We want to use one database for write and second for read-only

Comment: @PraveenKumar that exactly what master slave replication is for.

Comment: so please implement master-slave replication

Comment: @AtulAkabari :- If you have any link to implement master-slave replication than can you please share.

Comment: if you want to configure master -slave replication then use this link 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql
if you want to configure master-master replication then use this link
https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/configure-master-master-mysql-database-replication/